# HttpOnly cross domain cookie fails to be set

Tags: php, vue.js, cookies, cross-domain

After a week of reading almost every article and SO question out there, I've not been able to solve this.

I have:

- a (Php)API hosted locally on Nginx at https://api.domain.com(self signed tls certificate)
  Cors handling before all the routes are hit, e.g:

```
public function headers() {
        if (in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"], SecretsCollection::ALLOWED_ORIGINS)) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_ORIGIN"]);
        }

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "OPTIONS")
        {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Cookie, Content-Type, Authorization, Access-Token, Refresh-Token, Auth-Code, Test-Vue, Test-Insomnia");

            exit(0);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

So I'm allowing the frontend because I've declared it in my SecretsCollection.
This method is called before the router is initialized(in the bootstrapping process).

- a Vue.js frontend automatically hosted on Express at https://frontend.com:8081(        `https: true`  in vue.config.js)(not a subdomain, a completely different domain)

What I want to do:

The API, at one point will return an access_token and I want to save that in an HttpOnly cookie, problem is I can't. To test this I wrote this small function in the API:

```
public function setCookie()
    {
        setcookie("access_test_token", "access_token", [
            "expires" => time() + 3600 + 3600,
            "path" => "/",
            "secure" => true,
            "httponly" => true,
            "samesite" => "None"
        ]);
    }
```

This should set a cookie in the browser, but it doesn't. Testing this in Insomnia or Postman works and the cookie is set.

On the frontend, in the Login view, on mount I make this request:

```
axios
    .get(this.api + "/test")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data) // returns nothing because the function at this endpoint also returns nothing, but the cookie should be set at this point
    });
```

Then, to try and send the cookie back(assuming the API sets it in the first place), I make this request:

```
test: function() { // can be called on a button click
      axios
      .get(this.api + "/test-cookie",
            withCredentials: true
          })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
          });
    }
```

And that endpoint simply returns `getallheaders()`, and Cookie is not there.

On Firefox, the cookie gets rejected `Cookie “” has been rejected as third-party.` because I've blocked third party cookies, if I unblock them(also on Chrome) the cookie will still not be set.

This API should be public and accessible from different frontends, how can I achieve setting a HttpOnly cookie when I don't know what the frontend will be?!